# How do you use roll_cor {roll} in R?

Tags: r, scale, correlation, rolling-computation

There are various ways to perform rolling correlations in R; the most common appears to be through `rollapply` or `rollapplyr` in the `zoo` package.  That said, I wanted to test speeds between `rollapply` and `roll_cor`, but am confused by the parameters and results of `roll_cor`, and was not able to find adequate explanation.

The vignette for `roll_cor` can be found here: https://rdrr.io/cran/roll/man/roll_cor.html.  The Vignette includes the following:

> Details
> :  The denominator used gives an unbiased estimate of the covariance, so if the weights are the default then the divisor n - 1 is obtained.

> Value:  A cube with each slice the rolling and expanding correlations.

> center: logical. If TRUE then the weighted mean of each variable is used, if FALSE then zero is used.

> scale: logical. If TRUE then the weighted standard deviation of each variable is used, if FALSE then no scaling is done.

I simply do not understand the Details or Value section, and am confused over the effect of using or removing scaling and centering (correlations should always be between 0 and 1, regardless of whether the underlying data is centered and/or scaled - at least that is my understanding).  It is also unclear as to what parameters within the function produce a rolling correlation vs an expanding correlation.

Using the example provided in the vignette, but with larger numbers to exemplify the unexpected effect of removing both scaling and centering:

```
n <- 15
x <- rnorm(15, mean = 10)
y <- rnorm(15, mean = 10)

# rolling correlations with complete windows

>roll_cor(x, y, width = 5)

[1]          NA          NA          NA          NA -0.45645766  0.12947974  0.32558795
[8]  0.68633263  0.77727283  0.69960405  0.54084176  0.49984867  0.13242963  0.03916923
[15] -0.04331108

# results between 0 and 1, as expected
```

However, with center and scale = FALSE:

```
> roll_cor(x, y, width = 5, center = FALSE, scale = FALSE)

 [1]       NA       NA       NA       NA 117.0896 122.6121 132.8337 133.5465 138.7618 139.0836
[11] 136.0298 127.2654 128.9791 124.5726 126.7890

# results far outside of 0 and 1, and some 10x larger than the initial values of x and y.
```

Any clarification on the above (including parameters to define rolling vs. expanding correlations) would be greatly appreciated.  I believe any insight would help support the online knowledge base related to `roll_cor`.